# Customizing PasswordResetView using Django auth views

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Well, I need to create a customized view based on Django's PasswordReset view, but for when the User is already logged in. I originally used PasswordChangeView for this, but it automatically redirect the user to PasswordChangeForm, where the user inputs the older password and the new password and then save it. But, for a matter of security, I was requested to, when the user clicks the link to change their password, it automatically send a Password Reset email to they, showing the 'password_reset_done.html' and sending the password reset password. (Don't know if I'm making myself really clear I'm currently studying and this is my first time using stack overflow.

I already a custom_password_change view that uses PasswordResetView.

```
`def custom_password_change(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user

        if user.is_authenticated:
            # Call the Django built-in view for password reset
            return PasswordResetView.as_view(
                template_name='registration/password_change_form.html',
                email_template_name='registration/password_change_email.html',
                success_url='/password_change/done/'
            )(request)

    return render(request, "registration/password_change_form.html")`
```

But it stills demands user to input their email on the PasswordResetForm and then sends the email. I need it to send the email when the user clicks "change password" instead and returning the 'password_reset_done.html' template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two views.
The first view to request for email and implement post request to send the reset password email. i.e

```
class PasswordRequestView(View):
    template_name = "request_password_change.html"
    email_sent_template = 'email_sent_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # rendering the request password form
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST.dict()
        email = data.get('email', None)
        print('email => ', email)
        # send the generated url to this email
        # i.e http://localhost:6065/password-change/<access_key>/
        generated_url = "http://0.0.0.0:6005/password-change/wJalrXUtnFEMIK7MDENGbPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY/"
        # you can send this url via email. the user will click on this url to reset pass.
        return render(request, self.email_sent_template, {"access_url": generated_url})
```

the second view to capture the shared url(via email) and post request to reset password. i.e

```
class PasswordChangeView(View):
    template_name = "password_change_form.html"
    password_reset_success = 'password_reset_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        access_key = kwargs.get('access_key', '')
        print('access key => ', access_key)
        # do more validations here and return reset password form
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST.dict()
        print(data)
        # reset password here

        return render(request, self.password_reset_success)
```

Note: the urls in this case will be like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('request-password-change/', views.PasswordRequestView.as_view(),
         name='request-pass-change'),
    path('password-change/<str:access_key>/',
         views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='pass-change'),
]
```